# "Set as Base" button disappeared in jsfiddle

Tags: jsfiddle

Earlier "Set as Base" button was there in jsfiddle.net. Now it disappeared. I am logged in with my username. What could be the reason?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem when I started a new fiddle without logging in (managed to log in during fiddle creation). But when I created new fiddle via 'official' route (via dashboard) 'set as base' button appeared.

Comment: Thanks. It seems is the reason of Set as base button disappearance. To make it appear I: 1. logged in. 2. Clicked on Update; it then appeared in Dashboard. Then I opened it via Dashboard and the button is appeared as it should.

Comment: I had to create an entirely new fiddle to get the button back, but this approach worked. Just copied everything over from the old "anonymous" one and abandoned it - it didn't show up in my dashboard anyways. I suspect a bug in assigning a fiddle that was originally anonymous to a logged in user (even after forking sometimes?).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. If you don't want to create a new fiddle you can hit f12 (open dev panel) and search for `mark_favourite`. Remove the `hidden` attribute from the containing div and the button is back!

Answer (score 0):

Fork the fiddle, then set it as base will appear (at least for me it did).